# flickr.photos.search in python, get tags and exact geolocations for images

Tags: python, json, geolocation, tags, flickr

The following is the Python code I have so far. An example of the input file is

```
53.4667 -2.2333 Manchester
52.4831 -1.8936 Birmingham
53.4000 -3.0000 Liverpool
48.8567 2.3508 Paris
45.7600 4.8400 Lyon
43.2964 5.3700 Marseille
43.7034 7.2663 Nice
```

I input the lat and lon of different cities, using accuracy 11, which is city level. All I want to retrieve is the tags of all images at that location along with the exact geo-locations of that image. I am new to python and I don't think this code is achieving exactly this any help would be appreciated!

```
import flickrapi

api_key = "key"
secret_api_key = "secret key"
flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, secret_api_key)

def obtainImages():

    file = open('citylist.txt')
    for line in file:
        fields = line.strip().split()
        lat = fields[0]
        lon = fields[1]
        photo_list = flickr.photos.search(api_key=api_key, lat=lat, lon=lon, accuracy=11, format='parsed-json', per_page='100')

        print(photo_list)

 obtainImages()
```